# children is not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a array with a nested parent-child structure. I need to recursively go through this array and find wanted element. I wrote this function:

component child, this component calls itself, and displays on behalf of each child:

List.vue

```
   <template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" >
            <div v-if="item.data != null " >
                <template v-if="Object.keys(item.data).length > 0">
                    <template v-for="(item, index) in item.data" >

                    <v-simple-table :key="index">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="d-flex flex-row">
                            {{ '░'.repeat(count) }} {{count.length}} {{ item['name'] }}
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </v-simple-table>

                    </template>
                </template>
            </div>
            <div v-if="item.children != null " >
                <template v-if="Object.keys(item.children).length > 0">
                    <template v-for="(itemD, indexD) in item.children" >
                    <List :key="indexD" name="List" :items="itemD" :count="count + 1" />
                    </template>
                </template>
            </div>
            <div v-else></div> 
        </div>         
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'List',
        props: {
            items: {
                type: [Array, Object],
                default: [],
            },
            count: {
                type: [Number]
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

component parent, this component call component List:

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <v-row >
                <v-col>
                    <v-card>
                        <v-card-title>
                            Estruct
                        </v-card-title>
                        <v-row>
                                <List :items="desserts" :count="count + 1" />
                        </v-row>
                    </v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </div>
    </template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import List from "./List.vue";

    export default {
    components: { List },

    data: (vm) => ({
        desserts: [],
        count: 0
    }),
    watch: {
        config() {
            this.getData();
        },
    },
    methods: {
        getData() {
        let vm = this;
        // 
        //
        axios["get"](process.env.api_url + "/estruct", {
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("response", response.data);
                vm.desserts = response.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```

struct array is like, I am looking at this structure from console.log()

```
[
    {
        "data":[{}],
        "children":[]
    },
    {
        "data":[
                {
                "id":64,
                "name":"YSVERIS"
                }
            ],
        "children":[
                    {
                        "data":[
                                {
                                "id":85,
                                "name":"MERCEDES"
                                }
                            ],
                        "children":[]
                    },
                    {}
                ]
    },
    {
        "data":[
                {
                    "id":9,
                    "name":"YUDITH"
                }
                ],
        "children":[]
    },
    {
        "data":[
                {
                    "id":10,
                    "name":"YERNY DEL SOCORRO"
                }
                ],
    "children":[]
    },
    {
    "data":[
            {
                "id":11,
                "name":"NIDIA"
                }
            ],
    "children":[
                {
                    "data":[
                            {
                            "id":21,
                            "name":"VIVIKEY"
                            }
                        ],
                    "children":[]
                },
                {
                    "data":[
                            {
                                "id":18,
                                "name":"RODIMIRA "
                            }
                        ],
                    "children":[]
                }
            ]
    },
    {
    "data":[],
    "children":[]
    },
    {
    "data":[
            {
                "id":78,
                "name":"LUCRECIA"
            }
        ],
    "children":[]
    },
    {
    "data":[
            {
                "id":22,
                "name":"DAXI XIOMARA"
            }
        ],
    "children":[]
    }
]
```

currently the parent data is being displayed, but not the child data, it should work correct as far as I understand.   what do you think??? .......  recursive function is a function that calls itself until it doesn’t. And this technique is called recursion. A recursive function always has a condition to stop calling itself. Otherwise, it will call itself indefinitely. so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong....

I tested in component List.vue, before recursive in `<List key="indexD" name="List".......` I added this `{{ items }}`, so I could see the data object, something like: `[ { "data": [ { "id": 85, "name": "MERCEDES"} ] }]`

Here is the code in codesandbox  [code in codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sanne-jt9gz?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Where's the recursive function?

Comment: in vuej I call the view, so is in line <List :key="indexD"...... />

Comment: look https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-recursive-components

Comment: Hi, what is `este componente se llama a si mismo, y muestra en nombre de cada hijo` ? Also, do you have a [repro] for this one? It may help greatly debugging the thing.

Comment: let me up It to https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: hi!!! sorry, I hadn't thought of uploading the code, thanks for your suggestion, here is code 
 example https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sanne-jt9gz?file=/src/App.vue